# Converting Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> valueSelector, TValue[] values to Expression<Func<TElement, bool>>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

I'm trying to write a parsed text-to-EF query expression library.  Imagine a textbox where a user types a comma-delimited list of integers.  I'll split & parse it, and make an array of int's out of it.  But then I need to create an expression for it One of my requirements is to take `ctx => ctx.User.Receipts.Select(x => x.ReceiptID)` and a list of Receipt ID's (ints) and generate an `Expression` that does something like this:

`ctx.User.Where(x => x.Receipts.Any(y => listOfIds.Contains(y.ReceiptId));`

I think that it's signature would be something like this:

`Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateListExpression(Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> accessor, TProperty[] constantValues)`

and a sample usage would be something like this:

`ctx => ctx.User.Where(CreateListExpression(x => x.Receipts.Select(y => y.ReceiptId), new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });`

... but I'm flexible with 1 constraint.  In SQL, I'm looking for something comparable to this (in terms of how efficiently I'm retrieving the data & making sure the work is happing SQL-side):

```
select u.* 
from Users u 
join Receipts on r.UserID = u.UserID 
where r.ReceiptID in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are asking for is quite easy once you realize that

```
(Parent p) => p.Children.Any(c => filter(c.Property))
```

is equivalent to

```
(Parent p) => p.Children.Select(c => c.Property).Any(v => filter(v))
```

So the function could be like this

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> CreateListExpression<TEntity, TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, IEnumerable<TProperty>>> accessor, TProperty[] constantValues)
{
    Expression<Func<TProperty, bool>> predicate = v => constantValues.Contains(v);
    var body = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Any", 
        new[] { typeof(TProperty) }, accessor.Body, predicate);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, accessor.Parameters);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason why you need to generate these expressions dynamically, instead of just providing one function in your DAL for each potential query?

Your description sounds like the user just provides input values for queries, but not the integral structure of the query itself, in which case i wouldn't overcomplicate things. Your model could also pass the IQueryable around and modify as needed based on the users choices (add an arbitrary number of constraints, order stuff etc. etc.) instead of actually creating expressions form scratch.

If you really do need to go down a way of dynamic expression way, can you specify your question more? I'm not quire sure what the actual question is then.
You could build expressions yourself of course. Imho, this is a world of pain though, creating non-trivial expressions by hand is.. not particularly fun. So if there's another way, I would usually recommend chosing the other way.

Answer (score 0):

I am also unsure how you intend to define dynamically these properties, but the way you come up with seems to make it hard. I would just resort to a good old placeholding technique. Try something like the common parameterReplacer:

```
public class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly ParameterExpression m_parameter;
    private readonly Expression m_replacement;
    public ParameterReplacer(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression replacement)
    {
        this.m_parameter = parameter;
        this.m_replacement = replacement;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (object.ReferenceEquals(node, m_parameter))
            return m_replacement;
        return node;
    }

}
```

and then you define an extension method, that is supposed to replace your parameter in an expression.

```
public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T1, TResult>> FixParam<T1, T2, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T1, T2, TResult>> expression, T2 parameterValue)
    {
        var parameterToRemove = expression.Parameters.ElementAt(1);
        var replacer = new ParameterReplacer(parameterToRemove, Expression.Constant(parameterValue, typeof(T2)));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T1, TResult>>(replacer.Visit(expression.Body), expression.Parameters.Where(p => p != parameterToRemove));
    }
}
```

here it is the second parameter, but you can of course easily change it.
Now with this, i would define my final Predicates directly with the additional placeholder, e.g:

```
Expression<Func<User, int[], bool>> queryDefinition = (user, receiptIds) => user.Receipts.Any(r => receiptIds.Contains(r.Id));
```

and then replace the second parameter when you have a value

```
var ids = new []{3, 6};
var finalquery = queryDefinition.FixParam(ids);
```

this gives you the advantage of not having to worry about any expression tree building, and you have full control over your predicates in code.
PS: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Widget/T3oj5U